# SQL update only values whose value is not already updated

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have a Query it updates the whole tickets in table.
I want it to update only the tickets whose values needs to be updated not update all rows.
e.g.
If slabreachdays is already 10 then new value is also 10 it should not update.
This is my update query.

```
update ticket 
set TICKET.slabreachdays =
FLOOR(((DAYS(TICKET.creationdate) - DAYS(current timestamp)+10) 
* 86400 + (MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(TICKET.creationdate) -
MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(current timestamp)))/86400.0)
where TICKET.VENDOR like 'ABC' 
and TICKET.STATUS NOT IN('CANCELLED','CLOSED')
```

This is my select query which selects only the tickets that needs to be updated. This is the query I need to convert to an update query

```
select * from (
    select ticketid,slabreachdays,
    FLOOR(((DAYS(TICKET.creationdate) - DAYS(current timestamp)+10) * 86400 + (MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(TICKET.creationdate) - MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(current timestamp)))/86400.0)
    as newValue
    from ticket
    where TICKET.MLOUTSOURCEVENDOR like 'ABC' and TICKET.STATUS NOT IN('CANCELLED','CLOSED'))
where SLABREACHDAYS != newValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

Where .... And slabeachdays<> aller calculated expression

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
update ticket 
set TICKET.slabreachdays =
FLOOR(((DAYS(TICKET.creationdate) - DAYS(current timestamp)+10) 
* 86400 + (MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(TICKET.creationdate) -
MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(current timestamp)))/86400.0)
where TICKET.VENDOR like 'ABC' 
and TICKET.STATUS NOT IN('CANCELLED','CLOSED') and
TICKET.slabreachdays <>
(FLOOR(((DAYS(TICKET.creationdate) - DAYS(current timestamp)+10) 
* 86400 + (MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(TICKET.creationdate) -
MIDNIGHT_SECONDS(current timestamp)))/86400.0))
```